# Which part of the Shahnameh is the work of Daqiqi?

Tags: persian-language, shahnameh, ferdowsi, daqiqi

The classical Persian epic poem [the Shahnameh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahnameh) (a compilation and retelling of previous mythological and historical Persian literature) is mostly credited to [Ferdowsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdowsi), who spent over thirty years (977-1010 CE) composing it. However, the first person who started working on this versification was [Daqiqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daqiqi), who died in 977 CE after writing 1000 verses. These thousand verses were included in the Shahnameh by Ferdowsi when he compiled it, and apparently the difference in style between Daqiqi's and Ferdowsi's writing is still observable when you read the original text today.

**Where in the Shahnameh are those 1000 verses?** I'm reading [Helen Zimmern's translation available online](http://www.iranchamber.com/literature/shahnameh/shahnameh.php), which is divided into 18 sections; where within this story can we find the work of Daqiqi?

Answer (score 1):

there are approximately 1000 verses. in the version that you're mentioning it will be start of [16. isfendiyar](https://www.iranchamber.com/literature/shahnameh/16isfendiyar.php), until

> Now when Arjasp learned that the might of Isfendiyar was fettered...

if you can read persian text, it's:
[start of Goshtasp's rule](https://ganjoor.net/ferdousi/shahname/goshtasp/sh2) till [here](https://ganjoor.net/ferdousi/shahname/goshtasp/sh25)